# Mocking a Future Or in a Scala Spec

Tags: scala, mockito, specs2

I'm having trouble with Mockito to mock a response from a method that returns either an `Object` or an `Exception`. The mocked method's signature looks like this:

`def findResult(request: String): Future[Seq[String] Or MyException] =`

and in my Specs I'm trying to just return a succesful `Future`:

`when(client.findResult("1234")) thenReturn Future.successful[Seq[String] Or MyException](Seq("Hello"))`

This of course does not compile but what is the correct syntax?

Comment: well you need to decide what you want to return. Depending on the test, you may want to return the left or the right side of the `Or`. Eg. `doReturn(Future.successful(Seq("hello"))).when(client).findResult("1234")`

Comment: @rethab Nice one, thanks! If you put this as an answer I will accept...

Comment: there you go :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well you need to decide what you want to return. Depending on the test, you may want to return the left or the right side of the `Or`.

Eg.

`doReturn(Future.successful(Seq("hello"))).when(client).findR‌​esult("1234")`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot stub both on the same. But you can stub it as two different invocations like below.

```
when(client.findResult("1234")).thenReturn(Future.successful(Seq("test"))).thenReturn(Future.failed(new MyException()))
```

We are stubbing "findResult" to return Future[Success] the first time and Future[Failure] the second time.

Comment: Does this actually work? Getting a type mismatch error when try to compile this